# how to get bottom error message from a nested exception using mockmvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I am getting a nested exception like below for my Junit tests:

```
 Caused by: com.exception.Test1RestException: operation failed for test1 
at com.testController.tests(Test1Controller.java:123)
```

............................

```
  Caused by: com.exception.Test2Exception: operation failed for test2 
at com.testController.tests(Test2Controller.java:456)
```

.............................

```
 Caused by: com.exception.Test3RestException: operation failed for test3 
at com.testController.tests(Test2Controller.java:789)
```

I want to verify "operation failed for test3 " using mockmvc,used below

code for that

```
org.assertj.core.api.Assertions
        .assertThatThrownBy(() -> 
 mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/test/abc").file((MockMultipartFile) files))
              .andExpect(status().isOk()))
        .hasMessageContaining(operation failed for test3)
```

But I am getting expected error message as "operation failed for 
test1",any pointers to reach till bottom message here from my junit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked by using .hasStackTraceContaining(message) ,method call